# Affdex Gradle Failed to resolve

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, affdex-sdk

I’m not able to add dependency. It keeps throwing me the error:
 `Failed to resolve com.affectiva.android:affdexsdk:3.2` .
I’ve added maven repository but still it’s giving me error.

Project Gradle:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    maven { url "http://maven.affectiva.com" }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
}
```

App Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.affectiva.android:affdexsdk:3.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I get this following error

```
Error:(28, 13) Failed to resolve: com.affectiva.android:affdexsdk:3.2
```

Comment: Your gradle setup should work however http://maven.affectiva.com/ reports a problem: "The specified bucket does not exist" I would ask in the [official community of Affectiva](http://discuss.affectiva.com/) if there are any problems related to the repo.

Comment: @Gladwin we (at Affectiva) are aware of this issue and working on a fix for it. Thanks for trying out SDK, stay tuned for more updates as they happen.

Comment: @mostafazh please fix it at the earliest so that I can start exploring affectiva sdk

Comment: The issue with the repo has been resolved, please give it another try.

Comment: @AndyDennie it's working now